# my slide(jquery) menu is jumping, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to make a set of divs that if i click one of them the rest will hide using jquery's slideToggle, but every time i click a div (except the first time) it slides up and down multiple times. here is my code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  var cntln=0;
  function generate(){
   $.ajax({url: 'xmlsample.xml', async: false, success: function (d) {
    $(d).find('linea').each(function () {
     agregarlinea($(this).attr("nombre"));
    });
   }});
  }
  function agregarlinea(n) {
   var ndiv = document.createElement('div');
   ndiv.id = "dv"+cntln;
   ndiv.style.height="100px";
   ndiv.style.border="1px solid";
   ndiv.onmouseover=function(){darken(event.target.id)};
   ndiv.onmouseout=function(){lighten(event.target.id)};
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(ndiv);
   cntln++;
  }
  function darken(e) {
   document.getElementById(e).style.backgroundColor="#D3D3D3";
   document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
   var i;
   $("#"+e).click(function(){
    for (i=0; i<=cntln; i++) {
     if (("dv"+i) != e){
      $("#dv"+i).slideToggle("fast","swing");
     }
    }
   });
  }
  function lighten(i) {
   document.getElementById(i).style.backgroundColor="#FFFFFF";
   document.body.style.cursor = "default";
  }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body id="bod" onload="generate()">
  <h1 style="text-align:center">Dashboard</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

here is the "xmlsample.xml" file:

```html
<dashboard>
    <linea nombre="Allen1">
        <maquina nombre="Clipper1" cantidad="50" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="0" d="64.7" v="95.6" c="79"></maquina>
        <maquina nombre="Clipper2" cantidad="60" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="50" d="76.28" v="75.18" c="79.8"></maquina>
        <maquina nombre="Extruder" cantidad="55" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="51" d="70.56" v="56.08" c="36.62"></maquina>
        <maquina nombre="Empacadora" cantidad="37" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="81" d="19.84" v="36.16" c="48.16"></maquina>
        <maquina nombre="Mesh" cantidad="40" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="82" d="42.52" v="38.9" c="48.46"></maquina>
        <maquina nombre="Filtro" cantidad="12" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="100" d="23.98" v="80.14" c="57.2"></maquina>
  <paro tipo="fallo mecanico" numero="5"></paro>
  <paro tipo="temperatura" numero="7"></paro>
  <paro tipo="emergencia medica" numero="2"></paro>
  <paro tipo="cambio de bobina" numero="1"></paro>
  <paro tipo="Almuerzo" numero="16"></paro>
  <paro tipo="cambio de bobina" numero="1"></paro>
    </linea>
    <linea nombre="Allen2">
        <maquina nombre="Clipper1" cantidad="50" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="0" d="64.7" v="95.6" c="79"></maquina>
        <maquina nombre="Clipper2" cantidad="60" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="50" d="76.28" v="75.18" c="79.8"></maquina>
        <maquina nombre="Extruder" cantidad="55" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="51" d="70.56" v="56.08" c="36.62"></maquina>
        <maquina nombre="Empacadora" cantidad="37" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="81" d="19.84" v="36.16" c="48.16"></maquina>
        <maquina nombre="Mesh" cantidad="40" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="82" d="42.52" v="38.9" c="48.46"></maquina>
        <maquina nombre="Filtro" cantidad="12" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="100" d="23.98" v="80.14" c="57.2"></maquina>
  <paro tipo="fallo mecanico" numero="5"></paro>
  <paro tipo="temperatura" numero="7"></paro>
  <paro tipo="emergencia medica" numero="2"></paro>
  <paro tipo="cambio de bobina" numero="1"></paro>
  <paro tipo="Almuerzo" numero="16"></paro>
  <paro tipo="cambio de bobina" numero="1"></paro>
    </linea>
    <linea nombre="buhler1">
        <maquina nombre="Clipper1" cantidad="50" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="0" d="64.7" v="95.6" c="79"></maquina>
        <maquina nombre="Clipper2" cantidad="60" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="50" d="76.28" v="75.18" c="79.8"></maquina>
        <maquina nombre="Extruder" cantidad="55" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="51" d="70.56" v="56.08" c="36.62"></maquina>
        <maquina nombre="Empacadora" cantidad="37" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="81" d="19.84" v="36.16" c="48.16"></maquina>
        <maquina nombre="Mesh" cantidad="40" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="82" d="42.52" v="38.9" c="48.46"></maquina>
        <maquina nombre="Filtro" cantidad="12" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="100" d="23.98" v="80.14" c="57.2"></maquina>
  <paro tipo="fallo mecanico" numero="5"></paro>
  <paro tipo="temperatura" numero="7"></paro>
  <paro tipo="emergencia medica" numero="2"></paro>
  <paro tipo="cambio de bobina" numero="1"></paro>
  <paro tipo="Almuerzo" numero="16"></paro>
  <paro tipo="cambio de bobina" numero="1"></paro>
    </linea>
    <linea nombre="buhler2">
        <maquina nombre="Clipper1" cantidad="50" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="0" d="64.7" v="95.6" c="79"></maquina>
        <maquina nombre="Clipper2" cantidad="60" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="50" d="76.28" v="75.18" c="79.8"></maquina>
        <maquina nombre="Extruder" cantidad="55" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="51" d="70.56" v="56.08" c="36.62"></maquina>
        <maquina nombre="Empacadora" cantidad="37" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="81" d="19.84" v="36.16" c="48.16"></maquina>
        <maquina nombre="Mesh" cantidad="40" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="82" d="42.52" v="38.9" c="48.46"></maquina>
        <maquina nombre="Filtro" cantidad="12" planeado="100" producto="Chicharrones" turno="2" ooe="100" d="23.98" v="80.14" c="57.2"></maquina>
  <paro tipo="fallo mecanico" numero="5"></paro>
  <paro tipo="temperatura" numero="7"></paro>
  <paro tipo="emergencia medica" numero="2"></paro>
  <paro tipo="cambio de bobina" numero="1"></paro>
  <paro tipo="Almuerzo" numero="16"></paro>
  <paro tipo="cambio de bobina" numero="1"></paro>
    </linea>
</dashboard>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding the click handler inside the `darken()` function, so it gets bound over and over. You should bind the click handler inside the `agregarlinea()` function instead.

```
function agregarlinea(n) {
    var ndiv = document.createElement('div');
    ndiv.id = "dv" + cntln;
    ndiv.style.height = "100px";
    ndiv.style.border = "1px solid";
    ndiv.onmouseover = function () {
        darken(event.target.id)
    };
    ndiv.onmouseout = function () {
        lighten(event.target.id)
    };
    $(ndiv).click(function () {
        var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
        for (var i = 0; i <= cntln; i++) {
            if (("dv" + i) != thisId) {
                $("#dv" + i).slideToggle("fast", "swing");
            }
        }
    });
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(ndiv);
    cntln++;
}

function darken(e) {
    document.getElementById(e).style.backgroundColor = "#D3D3D3";
    document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92v1q4ad/)

Comment: @Matthew - What better place to bind the click-handler than just after you create the div?